# $K \unlhd A \rightarrow \Phi(A)$ is isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

> Let $\Phi: G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ be a surjective homomorphism. Prove that there is 1-1 correspondence between subgroups that contain $K=\text{Ker}(\Phi)$ and subgroups in $G_2$

I tried proving directly that there is a bijection, given by:

$$K\leq A\rightarrow \Phi(A) $$

**Injective:** It is injective, because if $\Phi(A)=\Phi (B)$, we must have that for every $a\in A$, $\exists b\in B$ such that $\Phi(a)=\Phi(b)\Rightarrow \Phi(ab^{-1})=1\Rightarrow a=b k, $ where $k\in K$. Thus, $a\in B$, because $K\leq B$. This means that $A\subset B$. By symmetry, $A=B$.

**Surjective:** Let $H\leq G_2$. We must have $1\in H$, thus $K\leq \Phi^{-1}(H)$. $\Phi \Phi^{-1}(H)=H$, as pointed out by @Stinking Bishop in the comments.

Is there a nicer way to do this using the isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not given with $\Phi$ being a _surjective_ homomorphism?

Comment: You are right! Sorry. It should be surjective. I have edited the post just now.

Comment: Then, surely $H=\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(H))$ won't be hard to prove. Let me start: $\subseteq$: $h\in H$ means $h=\Phi(g)$ for some $g\in G_1$ (surjectivity) and so $g\in\Phi^{-1}(H)$ and $h=\Phi(g)\in\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(H))$ etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't thinking about that assumption. It is really straightforward to finish my proof. Still, do you think there is a neater way to conclude this using the isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Well, probably, but to give you the complete answer I would need to know exactly the statements of the isomorphism theorems in your particular course - those may vary slightly across the world.

Comment: There is an isomorphism $\bar{\Phi}: G_1/ K\rightarrow \text{Im}(\Phi)$, such that $\bar{\Phi}\pi =\Phi$, where $\pi: g\rightarrow gK$.

Answer (score 1):

There is 1-1 correspondence between $\{ A\leq G_1 : K\leq A\}$ and subgroups of $\pi (G_1) = G_1 / K$.

**surjective:** as $\pi$ is surjective, for every subgroups $C \leq G_1 / K$ exists $\pi ^ {-1} (C) \geq K$.

**injective:** If $K \leq A \neq B \leq G_1$, then there is $a \in A$ (without loss of generality) s.t. $\forall b \in B$  $a\neq b$. Thus, $aK \neq bK$ $\forall b \in B$, then $\pi(A) = A/K \neq B/K = \pi(B)$.

$\pi(G_1) = G_1 / K \cong \Phi (G_1)$, due to isomorphism theorem, and there is 1-1 correspondence between their subgroups.

Comment: So clever!  I have two doubts though: 1) Could you be a bit more lengthsome about the surjectivity part? I did not follow the part where $\pi^{-1}(C) \geq K$ and $\pi(\pi^{-1}(C))=C$   2) If there is an isomorphism between groups $\pi(G_1)\approx G_1/K \approx \Phi(G_1)$, why is there an isomorphism between subgroups?

Comment: 1) $\pi : G_1 \rightarrow G_1 / K$, s.t. $\pi (g) = gK$, in particular $\pi (e) = K$. $K \leq \pi ^{-1} (C)$, because $ e \in C$. $\pi (\pi ^{-1} (C)) = C$ by definition: $\pi ^{-1} (C) = {g\in G_1 : \pi (g) \in C }$

2) There is bijection between subgroups of $G_1 / K$ and subgroups of $\Phi (G_1)$, i.e. for any $H \leq G_1 / K$ there is only one $\widehat{H} \leq \Phi(G_1)$ isomorphic to it.

Comment: 1)  Okay. Every subgroup $C$ of $G_1/K$ is such that $1K\in C$, so for every $k\in K$, $\pi(k)=k K=1K\in C$. Thus $K\subset \pi^{-1}(C)$. Why is $C\subset \pi(\pi^{-1}(C))$ though?   2) Still not sure I follow your reasoning... Sorry, this is my first group theory class.